# Amazon MWS Orders API - Check if Order was refunded

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Here's the sample response I got from calling `/Orders` with `Action=GetOrder`.

```
+"Order": array:100 [▼
    0 => SimpleXMLElement {#491 ▼
      +"LatestShipDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      +"OrderType": "StandardOrder"
      +"PurchaseDate": "2017-01-17T01:44:52Z"
      +"AmazonOrderId": "701-#######-#######"
      +"IsReplacementOrder": "false"
      +"LastUpdateDate": "2017-01-17T01:46:09Z"
      +"NumberOfItemsShipped": "0"
      +"ShipServiceLevel": "Expedited"
      +"OrderStatus": "Canceled"
      +"SalesChannel": "Amazon.ca"
      +"IsBusinessOrder": "false"
      +"NumberOfItemsUnshipped": "0"
      +"IsPremiumOrder": "false"
      +"EarliestShipDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      +"MarketplaceId": "### ###"
      +"FulfillmentChannel": "AFN"
      +"PaymentMethod": "Other"
      +"IsPrime": "false"
      +"ShipmentServiceLevelCategory": "Expedited"
      +"SellerOrderId": "#### #### #"
    }
```

Is there a way to check if Order was refunded by specifying the OrderID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. But, the way I'd do this is via the Finance API section. [ListFinancialEvents](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/Finances_ListFinancialEvents.html) operation returns [FinancialEvents](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/Finances_Datatypes.html#FinancialEvents) object. That should return all refund events on an order, if any.

Comment: Thanks, on the `FinancialEvents` I just have to look for `<RefundEventList/>` if not empty.